# How to center the caption inside /Figure in IEEE Access

Tags: floats, ieeetran, overleaf, ieee-style, resize

[IEEE Access' Latex template](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-access/) uses its own figure class named \Figure

`\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt)[width=\linewidth]{fig1.png}{<caption>\label{fig1}}`

This command is for wide figures, that is, figures which span two columns. However I have two problems about that command:

1. In Scenario a; my figure fit on the page width but the caption is not centered and `including` caption as package at the beginning of document is resulted with many error related to figure. So it is not the solution. On the other hand in Scenario b; caption is centered automatically but my figure exceeds the page width.

   Scenario a: `\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt)[width=\linewidth]{fig1.png}{<caption>\label{fig1}}`

   Scenario b: `\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt){fig1.png}{<caption>\label{fig1}}`
2. Some large figures are placed on a blank page at the bottom instead of in the text and pushes all the other figures under it. So, the remaining page consists of all rest of the figures only.

Note: I'm using Overleaf as latex environment.

Comment: please list MWE with your code starting with `\documentclass` and finishing with `\end{document}`

Comment: I'm asking a general question really I don't think it is really necessary to list with example. But you can find the latex template of IEEE access from here: https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-for-ieee-access/

Comment: I think it is necessary to list an example. I tried the template you linked to and it doesn't contain a `\Figure` command showing either of the problems you listed. So it'd be nice to see the actual code you're using that generated these problems, rather than guessing at what code you have. Already you mentioned changing `[ht!]` in your answer, but the template's `.tex` file doesn't contain `[ht!]`, so you must have added or changed some figures in the template file to get something that shows the problems you listed.

Comment: Centering would be difficult, since you don't have control over \figurename etc.  In any case, if the manual doesn't allow it, don't do it.

Comment: Exactly, I don't have any control over \figure. Unless I resize my figure the caption is centered, directly, however I need to resize it. So I'm considering to resize before upload to latex directory. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Regarding "Unless I resize my figure the caption is centered, directly": you did not mention how exactly you resize your images. With the help of the width parameter or with something entirely different? Could you therefore please add a minimal working example showing a working, not resized image in comparison to a non working but resized image?

Comment: I'm using the below example into my .tex for the template. It is working example for IEEE Access Template. If I resize by using [width=\linewidth] before {fig1.png}, caption is not centered. If I don't use the parameter ([width=\linewidth]) like in below 2 then my figure exceeds the page but caption is centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to put in center the caption as an answer for my first question.

However, for the second question when I changed [ht!] to [!h] the problem is solved.

```
\Figure[!h](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt)[width=1\linewidth]{my_image.png}{my caption \label{fig:block}}
```

Comment: In a normal figure*, [h] is not implemented.  Also, these options are implemented as bit flags, so order doesn't matter.  Finally, [!] has no effect unless you have several floats on one page.

Comment: I have several floats on the page and this figure type is different then the default one. IEEE Access is specifically using this \figure tag to define figure. Thanks anyway, I solved my issue and I'm leaving for people who have or will have the same struggle with me.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does \begin{figure}...\end{figure} still work?  It could be that \Figure is just a simplified version.

Comment: I tried at the beginning since I had many other problems with this tag. So, It does work but doesn't fit with the template structure so you cannot use it. Besides, it gives lots of warnings and break many things in the text generally. So, \Figure is not simplified version, unfortunately.